# Ubuntu 20.10 upgrade from 20.04 - Black Screen with only mouse pointer after auto-login

Tags: .desktop, 20.10

Ok, I can see there are loads of similar questions regarding many distro upgrades but none of the solutions or suggestions have worked for me.

**Problem**
I upgraded my Dell XPS laptop from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 via the distro upgrade option.  Since doing so, I am having problems with my desktop whereby after auto-login, I end up with a black screen with only the mouse cursor and no window decorations, taskbar etc.

**Comments**

- My auto-login flashes the new standard Ubuntu background for about 5 seconds then the screen goes black.
- The mouse pointer is visible
- I can right click the black screen and start a terminal session, from where I can run applications from the command line
- Any windowed application I run has no title bar, appears in the top left corner of the screen and cannot be moved nor resized
- I created a new user and it logs in with a normal desktop in its initial state
- I have tried `dconf reset -f /`
- I have tried `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity`
- I have tried renaming my entire `.config` folder and rebooting
- If I change the scale with `xrandr` to 0.9x0.9, I can see a little bit of the "standard" background / wallpaper along the right side of the screen and the bottom of the screen
- If I open display settings with `gnome-control-center display` for my usual account there are options for multiple screens, even though I only have the laptop screen enabled.  In addition, there are no scale buttons on the scale settings section
- If I do the same for the test account I created, I get a single desktop settings screen and 100% & 200% buttons in the scale section
- I have tried completely removing the installed NVIDIA drivers (460), with no effect

I am now out of ideas, I'm not sure which config file in my user home is driving this.  I do have a backup that I took prior to the upgrade so I could roll back, but I'd rather solve the problem if possible.

Thanks for any advice. Obviously if I've missed detail or can provide further information, please advise.

Comment: I had black screen right after login screen accepted my username-password. I've managed to launch desktop after switching to Desktop on Wayland in GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so in this case the fix was to replace the `core.pb` file in the `~/.cache/compizconfig-1` folder.

Diagnostic route was

- rename `~/.cache` folder & reboot.  Problem solved
- rename `~/.cache/compizconfig-1` folder & reboot. Problem solved
- work through the recently changed (i.e. not old) files, renaming and rebooting.

`core.pb` was the culprit. The Desktop displays correctly when this file is replaced with the auto-created one. However, desktop configuration is lost (taskbar icons etc.) although this *might* be because of the resetting I did initially.

Posted in case this is helpful for anybody else.

Comment: Where is core.pb located? What was the problem with it? It's related to recent kernel updates somehow?

Comment: @StayCool, core.pb is in the ~/.cache/compizconfig-1/ folder.  Had to delete it and allow the system to remake it for the display to "normalize".  I don't believe it's related to kernel updates, but I cannot confirm this.  Can't remember which kernel I was using in 20.10 before upgrading, but it was the newest for said release at the time.